# MongoDB document not saved but showing success

Tags: mongodb, axios

I have a problem. I'm trying to save answers from a survey. My problem is that I'm sending these answers through axios and they are showing in the console.log from the server, which means that my data is reaching the server safely. But data is not being saved. Also no error is shown.
**Server.js**

```
router.route('/answers')
    //post answers to database
    .put(function(req, res){
        var survey = new Survey();
        survey.name = req.body.name;
        survey.email = req.body.email;
        survey.q_id = req.body.q_id;
        survey.q_text = req.body.q_text;
        survey.answer = req.body.answer;
        console.log(Survey.collection)
        survey.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                return ;                
            }
            res.send(survey);
        });
    })
```

**Survey.js (Model)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var question = new Schema({
    q_text:String,
    order: Number,
    options:[{
        type: {type: String},
        value: {type: String}
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question',question);
```

**Code that is posting the data**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3100/api/answers';
axios.put(url, survey)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('Successfully posted');
    console.log(res);
    setSubmitting(false);
    setStatus({submitted: true});
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: Are you saying that the survey document is being correctly returned?  Try returning the document returned by the save function.  Your _id may not be being set to the _id you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    survey.save(function(err, savedSurvey){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return ;                
        }
        res.send(savedSurvey);
    });
```